# Intel AX200 Wifi card abruptly stopped working on Dual Boot system with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04, iwlwifi

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I am running a Dual Boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on an x570 Tomahawk MSI mobo (with built in wifi 6 through Intel AX200). For the last 6 months, there were no problems with the Intel AX200 Wifi card on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. However, recently, during a Zoom video call on Ubuntu 20.04, the nm-applet disappeared abruptly - cutting off internet access. To my surprise, after booting into Windows 10, the Wifi Card showed the dreaded Code 10 Intel error in device manager, and was not working! Even the Realtek Ethernet port stopped working, even though the physical hardware is being detected. I have had my secure boot switched off right from the beginning too for dual booting.

I have tried the following steps to diagnose/solve the error :

1. Verify that there is no softkill of the card using rfkill command (I put my system in suspend state often). Cold reboot did not help either.
2. Verify that the hardware is being detected by the kernel, I attach below the console output utilizing lspci |grep Intel
      `28:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)`
3. Checked for unclaimed networks using sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc700000-fc70ffff memory:fc710000-fc713fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
```

4. Check diagnostic messaging for Intel WiFi drivers using dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    5.215677] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.225416] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.304090] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.304103] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    5.304106] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.304107] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.304350] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.304859] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.437960] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.460876] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x3090001
[    6.460892] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: UMAC PC: 0xc00c0538
[    6.460906] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[    6.460908] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[    6.461033] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.461034] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: -480385611
[    6.461036] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode
[    6.461038] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xB79C7698 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    6.461040] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x0B67F302 | trm_hw_status0
[    6.461041] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xACE90FF8 | trm_hw_status1
[    6.461043] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xD37D2FB5 | branchlink2
[    6.461044] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xFEDB93A6 | interruptlink1
[    6.461045] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xFEA58ADC | interruptlink2
[    6.461046] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x67D2B540 | data1
[    6.461047] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x6CFB93BF | data2
[    6.461049] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x888F6DA5 | data3
[    6.461050] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xF5E71B51 | beacon time
[    6.461051] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x1775D5F0 | tsf low
[    6.461052] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x627FEE9C | tsf hi
[    6.461053] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x317DCF14 | time gp1
[    6.461055] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x4D7E8D4F | time gp2
[    6.461056] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x98ED5D87 | uCode revision type
[    6.461057] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xF0BD87A6 | uCode version major
[    6.461058] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xB1BFB652 | uCode version minor
[    6.461060] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xF66B7BB9 | hw version
[    6.461061] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x1E5568DC | board version
[    6.461062] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xB317C48E | hcmd
[    6.461063] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x53DFFAAF | isr0
[    6.461064] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x1552C32E | isr1
[    6.461065] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x9FDDDDDB | isr2
[    6.461067] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x55A14394 | isr3
[    6.461068] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x48BEFF96 | isr4
[    6.461069] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x1F5B955C | last cmd Id
[    6.461070] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xAD7DAE7F | wait_event
[    6.461071] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xB457FA86 | l2p_control
[    6.461073] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x9AFBFB6E | l2p_duration
[    6.461074] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xFBE31B3C | l2p_mhvalid
[    6.461075] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x784F9A11 | l2p_addr_match
[    6.461076] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xDF01A00C | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    6.461077] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xF0D2DDAA | timestamp
[    6.461079] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0xC6441993 | flow_handler
[    6.461124] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    6.461126] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    6.461127] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink2
[    6.461128] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    6.461129] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    6.461131] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data1
[    6.461132] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data2
[    6.461133] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    6.461134] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac major
[    6.461135] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[    6.461137] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | frame pointer
[    6.461138] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | stack pointer
[    6.461139] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    6.461140] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    6.461149] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    6.461153] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    6.461158] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    6.461162] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.461166] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    6.461171] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    6.461175] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    6.461179] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.461183] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.461188] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.461194] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.461201] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.461208] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    6.461212] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    7.156180] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

5. Checked my "iwlwifi" files using ls | grep iwfl in /lib/firmware

```
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
```

6. Verified my kernel number `5.8.0-59-generic` to check online if there could be potential bugs - as of now I have been unable to narrow down to the solution.

I would be grateful for any help from this community regarding my question; the hardware no longer functions in either of the OS installed.

PS : Gratitude to  [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) for his comments on other posts I have read to even help a relatively new Ubuntu user to this stage!

Comment: *"somehow Ubuntu 20.04 update has managed corrupting the driver file and the hardware no longer functions in either of the OS installed"* - This just not correct.  Windows and Ubuntu do not use the same "driver file".  If the hardware does not work on either OS, then the hardware has failed or is failing.  There are no files in common between the different operating systems.  "*I am aware from multiple posts that dual booting makes stable wireless card performance painful*" - this is also not true.  Again, there are no files or drivers in common.

Comment: Other questions about dual boot and wireless issues usually have to do with Windows' "fast startup" because it is actually a hybrid suspend that can interfere with the ability to mount drives and initialize hardware, since Windows doesn't actually shut down when you use this feature.  But this can't be the problem in your situation if your hardware also no longer works on Windows.  Unfortunately, if your hardware won't work on any OS, that's a pretty consistent indicator that the hardware just does not work anymore

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestions to improve this post @Nmath . As you rightly pointed out, the same driver file is not used by either OS - in that case, why is the hardware still being detected on the PCI bus via the lspci command, and also via the sudo lshw -C network command? The hardware is also detected on Windows during "scan for hardware changes" , the drivers would not however work.
I believe detection vs functioning are two different cases? Thank you for the help offered.

Comment: It's possible for hardware to be detected and still have some other hardware fault that prevents operation

Comment: Thank you for that point @Nmath , I was not aware of the same. What is befuddling is that my Ethernet port is blinking , it shows connected, but the internet refuses to start up - and the device shows internet access.

Comment: "Windows and Ubuntu do not use the same "driver file". If the hardware does not work on either OS, then the hardware has failed or is failing." I agree entirely with my colleague @Nmath . I am sorry that I have no better suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @chili555, I shall accept the answer that the hardware has failed then. And thank you for your help with different diagnostic commands, I look forward to continue learning with the community.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very kind comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested appropriately by users @Nmath and @chilli555, I had a hardware failure in my system which led to this state. For anyone interested, never blow pressurized air from a blower to clean dust from electronic components for long : if the air gets warm (thanks to the motor), it can condense on the electronics and failures can arise from short circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

My PC has AX200. I use Ubuntu and Windows. After Windows 11 Ubuntu 22 doesn't see any wifi adaptor. I fully switch off my PC (not reboot), drop cable from 220 Volts and after I start my PC. So after this steps Ubuntu 22 can works with AX200 again.